# Determine I2C read time

Tags: i2c

I'd like to determine how fast I can read sensor values on a bus given the bus rate/bandwidth. According to the device documentation found [here](https://www.melexis.com/en/product/MLX90614/Digital-Plug-Play-Infrared-Thermometer-TO-Can), assuming a 7-bit address there are 49 bits involved in sending & reading a single sensor temperature value. A picture is also shown here.
[image]
Would the transfer rate simply be 49 bits / 100kbps = 0.00049 seconds / read?

Comment: Please share how you determined that the number of bits to be transferred is 49.

Comment: Also, notice that this device uses SMBus, not I2C, and the differences between I2C and SMBus are important in answering your question.

Comment: @ThePhoton isn't SMBus essentially I2C except for different voltage levels and a different range of clock frequency values? In other words, by setting the clock frequency, I can assume a similar data transfer rate as I would for I2C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disregarding start, restart and stop conditions, that transaction is 6 bytes times 9 bits. If the PEC is optional, it's 5 bytes * 9 bits = 45 bits. The start, restart, and stop conditions may not equal a bit in duration, but can be roughly approximated as equaling a bit. So I count 48 bits, and in practice there is some software overhead.

So your estimation of 49 bits is approximately right, you can read a 16-bit word from the chip about 2040 times per second, or about every 0.49 milliseconds.

Keep in mind that this is the theoretical maximum throughput of the bus. Any other things that the software does will slow it down, and also if the slave needs to stretch the clock to slow down the communications.